# Hibernation in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, hibernate, 20.04

In "System Settings" -> "Power Manager" -> "Energy Saving" there is no "Hibernation" option.

File `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` created with content:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-m$
ResultActive=yes
```

Packages `pm-utils` and `uswsusp` installed.
Through `pm-hibernation` successfully leaves in hibernation mode.

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me with Kubuntu 20.04 and a swap partition of the same size of the available RAM. It's somewhat a simplification of other answers seen here and on [the other answer for Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04).

First of all: **no need** to install either `pm-utils`, `uswsusp` or `hibernate`: I don't have them in my system, however hibernation works with both `sudo systemctl hibernate` and with the hibernation button in KDE menu.

So, the whole procedure:

1. find the name and UUID of the swap partition

   `sudo swapon --show=NAME,UUID`

   (in my case it's `/dev/dm-2` - it must start with /dev, otherwise you're using a swap file)
2. edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the value for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` by adding the following at the end of the line (within `"`):

   `resume=UUID=<UUID>`

   (replace `<UUID>` with the UUID found previously)
3. Run `update-grub` to update the actual grub config based on `/etc/default/grub`
4. write the following command:

```
cat << "EOF" > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

5. logout and login

Now you can hibernate with either `sudo systemctl hibernate` or with the hibernation button in KDE menu.

Comment: Can confirm this procedure works fine for Kubuntu 20.04, no need for any of the utilities mentioned in a lot of other answers (i. e. pm-utils etc.).Since I've also seen some answers which recommend to create the file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: This step is definitely not necessary, but update-initramfs will start to "guess" the right UUID used for hibernation unless it's explicitely specified. In my experience this works just fine, though.

Comment: You should include, that this needs a swap-partition, while current OSes frequently use a [swap file as described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231829/830570)

Comment: @Cadoiz I did write this applies to Kubuntu 20.04 and a swap partition

Comment: Note that I did these steps using a swap logical volume rather than a raw partition and it worked for me. On logout I did get some scary looking errors that ended with "fixing recursive fault" but hard reseting ended up with a system that could hibernate fine and logout fine and everything. I hope that error doesn't haunt me in the future tho...

Answer (score 1):

I have created a swap file in `/home` partition.

1. Install pm-utils and uswsusp.

   ```
   sudo apt install pm-utils uswsusp
   ```
2. Create swapfile and give necessary permissions:

   ```
   fallocate -l 8G /home/swapfile && chmod 600 /home/swapfile && \
   mkswap /home/swapfile && swapon /home/swapfile
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`:

   ```
   cat << "EOF" > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
   [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes

   [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
   ResultActive=yes
   EOF
   ```
4. Get swap offset:

   ```
   swap-offset /home/swapfile
   ```
5. Get UUID of /home/swapfile:

   ```
   findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /home/swapfile
   ```
6. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=861920c2-557d-4910-9b3e-b8a7be8f4fae resume_offset=12900352"
   ```
7. Edit service systemd-logind.service:

   ```
   systemct edit systemd-logind.service
   ```

   and add

   ```
   [Service] 

   ProtectHome=read-only
   ```
8. Update the GRUB using `update-grub`
9. Reboot

Comment: After installing gcdemu, hibernation stopped working. I removed gcdemu.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without superuser-privileges?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this solution (the new buttons) on a Dell Precsion 5550, Ubuntu 20.04, with a USB3 docking station.
Result: While docked, it goes into hibernation, but on resume freezes.
If undocked before hibernate, it comes back out.
Conclusion: Not solid enough.

I am sticking to the `sudo systemctl hibernate` solution from [How to enable the hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)
It seems solid, and works both docked and non-docked.

PS. It would be nice to have a polished hibernate option in Ubuntu by default though.
(AND, while we are at it: It would be nice to get a real S3 sleep functioning on Dell Precision 5550,  current S1/S2 option eats battery)

Answer (score 1):

A couple years ago, when I got tired of setting up hibernation every time I installed system, I wrote the script that set it up automatically.

I tested it on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and now on Kubuntu 22.04 and it works fine for me.
It supports systems with a configured swap partition. If needed, it creates the necessary policy and changes to use hibernation when the lid is closed, and disables the grub boot menu after hibernation.

You can find it on GitHub: [configure-hibernate](https://github.com/almaceleste/configure-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify [Mauro's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316444/1578338) a bit to make hibernation fully work on my Kubuntu 22.04:

On forth step replace `/etc` with `/var/lib`:

```bash
~$ sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Then write the following to the file:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.free>
ResultActive=yes
```

As a result, the hibernation button works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested in GNOME 20.04 and working!**

First, get `sudo systemctl hibernate` working (see above answer).

Paste

```
[Enable hibernate in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

into `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

Install [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/) GNOME Shell Extension

And voilá, two options appear: 
* hibernate 
* hybrid sleep

Proof:
[image]

I want this to work by default in Ubuntu!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without superuser-privileges?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: It makes no sense to me, that I'm allowed to shutdown/hibernate/etc. via gui, but not via terminal...

Answer (score 0):

hibernation on kubuntu 21.04 (HP 845 G7).

0. Disable Secure boot...
1. make swap file (`/swapfile`)

```bsh
fallocate -l 16G /swapfile && chmod 600 /swapfile && \
mkswap /swapfile && swapon /swapfile
```

2. install `pm-utils`
3. get swap offset

```bsh
sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'<>
```

4. get the UUID of the partition where the `swapfile` lies

```bsh
findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /swapfile
```

5. edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `resume` and `resume_offset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`

```bsh
resume=UUID=b0644cc4-e29b-4302-acc5-f5954076ffd9 resume_offset=34816
```

6. `update-grub`
7. add polkit `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

```bsh
cat << "EOF" > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

7. reboot

Comment: Tried to improve your answer a bit. Is there a way to do this without superuser-privileges?