# How to enable the hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, hibernate

I tried different options to enable hibernation in Ubuntu 20.04 but nothing is working. How can I enable the hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Hibernate does not work with all equipment. Install the `pm-utils` package.

Answer (score 101):

I assume you have a **swap partition** ready to use (if you have a **swap file** you cannot hibernate using this method). Follow these steps:

1. Install `pm-utils` and `hibernate`:

   ```bash
   sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate
   ```
2. Then:

   ```bash
   cat /sys/power/state
   ```
3. You should see:

   ```
   freeze mem disk
   ```
4. Then run one of the following lines:

   ```bash
   grep swap /etc/fstab
   blkid | grep swap
   ```
5. Copy the `UUID` value. You will need it later.
6. Then run (use your favorite editor if not `nano`):

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
7. Change the line that says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   so that it instead says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<YOUR_COPIED_UUID>"
   ```

   Be careful not to miss the `UUID=` part.
8. Then, after saving the file and quitting the text editor, run:

   ```bash
   sudo update-grub
   ```
9. To test it, run:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl hibernate
   ```

---

This extension seems to enable showing the "Hibernate" menu entry, but it changes the overall look of this sub-menu: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/ .

---

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 using kernel version 5.4.0-31 on my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon.

Comment: I already tried this. 
~$ swapon 
NAME       TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda10 partition 17.7G 584K   -2

~$ grep swap /etc/fstab 
UUID=8fb05489-1d06-4e02-bb80-1ec8022410ee        none            swap    sw              0       0
#/swapfile none swap sw 0 0

~$ grep resume /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=a1d06496-6e35-4db5-be50-6171988216f0 ro  quiet splash resume=8fb05489-1d06-4e02-bb80-1ec8022410ee $vt_handoff

Comment: Works. :) it worked for me only with UUID.

Comment: just to mention this extension for gnome 36 / ubuntu 20.04, handy once the setup is done.


https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/

(check github page of the extension for additional configuration required by ubuntu)

Comment: That extension does not work for me on 20.04

Comment: What if `grep swap /etc/fstab` doesn't return a UUID?

Comment: Running `grep swap /etc/fstab` returns `/swapfile   none   swap    sw   0  0` . Any suggestion?

Comment: @MikeMarsian You need to switch to swap partition rather than a swap file. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1266913/816

Comment: It works, but even with a nice SSD, but hibernate resuming is a bit slower then a cold boot.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder Why switch to a swap partition when a swap file is perfectly fine for hibernation (assuming it's big enough). You just need to find the offset of the swap file and in addition to the `resume` parameter, pass a `resume_offset` parameter. This is described in detail on Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file

Comment: after making this, in xubuntu 20.10, grub started to make 30 seconds timeout. and, this may not be enough. i would like gui button, working without password. as an example of gui problems, there is hibernate entry in xfce user actions applet but, if to enable them, they appear but are grayed out.

Comment: and, hibernate is virtual and has no packages, in ubuntu 20.10

Comment: There is no UUID in Ubuntu 20.04. Thre is /dev/mapper/crypt_volume-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0 in the /ets/fstab only.

Comment: without a UUID, use the dm path for `resume` without the `UUID=` prefix, i.e.: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mapper/vg--main-lv--swap"`

Comment: Hibernation only works with swap partition.

Comment: Any idea why `cat /sys/power/state` only prints `freeze mem` ?

Comment: @abu_bua Take a look at your UEFI/BIOS settings. I was facing the same problem - had to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @sinchan yes, i had to disable secure boot. Got it already. It's a kernel issue, wondering if there is a workaround and let hibernation also work in secure boot.

Comment: For anyone using rEFind, add resume point in /boot/refind_linux.conf

Comment: don't forget the "UUID=" in the grub line! I wasted 2 days on that...

Comment: pm-utils doesn't seem required to me. Hiberation worked without it installed for me. What should it be for really? Thank You for the answer! And @Gavriel - You're right, it's easy to miss that I believe, thank You. I think I'll try editing the answer to reflect it.

Comment: I tried this method and wehn restarted the sytem I got a black screen with a cursor flashing at the upper left corner and stopped there. (I removed quiet in my boot command line parameters). Then I saw from this page https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file that mentioned "Configure the initramfs". I even cannot see this file `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` in my ubuntu 21.10. Is this initramfs really required? Thanks

Comment: If you have swap you cannot hibernate? And then you proceed to say prepare a swap file?

Comment: I'm getting the error: 
`E: Package 'hibernate' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @BrunoAmbrozio me too

Comment: I was also unable to install the 'hibernate' package. However, I proceeded with the installation and hibernation seems to be working fine (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: machine seem suspended after sudo systemctl hibernate. screen is off but power indicator is still on.

Answer (score 49):

If you want to use a **/swapfile** to hibernate instead of the swap partition:

The [top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241902/933016) works well, but **you don't have to use a partition**, you can also use a default `/swapfile`.

First of all, you [should increase the size of the /swapfile](https://linuxhint.com/change_swap_size_ubuntu/) at least to the size of your RAM.

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate uswsusp
   ```
2. Find your UUID and swap offset:

   ```
   findmnt -no UUID -T /swapfile && sudo swap-offset /swapfile
   ```

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   371b1a95-d91b-49f8-aa4a-da51cbf780b2
   resume offset = 23888916
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and replace the string:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   with your UUID and offset:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=371b1a95-d91b-49f8-aa4a-da51cbf780b2 resume_offset=23888916"
   ```
4. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Test your hibernation:

   ```
   sudo systemctl hibernate
   ```

Probably you should not change the size of your swap after enabling the hibernation (at least without changing the `swap-offset` in GRUB).

See [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file) for more details.

**EXTRA BONUS:** If you want to **hibernate when a laptop lid is closed** (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140362/933016)):

0. Disable any options in the settings that touch the laptop lid, set them to "do nothing".
1. Run:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/acpi/events/ && sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid
   ```

   and paste:

   ```bsh
   event=button/lid.*
   action=/etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh && sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh && sudo nano /etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh
   ```

   and paste:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   LOG_FILE='/var/log/laptop-lid.log'
   touch $LOG_FILE && chmod 0666 $LOG_FILE

   grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state
   if [ $? = 0 ]
   then
       # close action
       echo "$(date '+%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'): closed" >> $LOG_FILE
       systemctl hibernate
   else
       # open action
       echo "$(date '+%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'): opened" >> $LOG_FILE
   fi
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
   ```

Comment: Note: do not use the UUID returned by `mkswap` for `resume_offset`. The `mkswap` UUID is useless according to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946

Comment: This works for me. No need to use a *swap partition*. The *swap file* is enough.

Comment: This worked for me! I don't understand why all the answers use a swap partition... My brand new install of ubuntu came with a swapfile but no swap partition.

Comment: Don't know why but did'nt work for me (lubuntu 20.04) I had to make a swap partition and then it worked. Anyway it was an informative response.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, because `sudo systemctl hibernate` returns the error message, `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb "hibernate" not supported`. According to an internet search, hibernation is incompatible with Secure Boot. Do you concur?

Comment: @PaddyLandau: disable secure boot, as in https://devopsid.com/linux-machine-failed-to-hibernate-system-via-logind-sleep-verb-not-supported/

Comment: @LucianSasu — Thank you for that information. That's disappointing, because disabling secure boot reduces security. I'll just have to live without hibernation.

Comment: Once I got my grup updated right (it was reading more than just /etc/defaults/grub) this solution worked really well.

Comment: Thanks, works unexpectedly well! Also would like to share a perfect video how to resize your swap file, which helped me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSbBl31ohjE

Comment: Just tried this, and it seems to work, thank you! Question: [this setup guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html) also tells to update `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Could you add a comment in your answer – just for completeness – explaining why this is not necessary?

Comment: I get this strange log message when resuming from hibernation: "kernel:[ 923.730995] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 20 on CPU 0." "kernel:[ 923.730997] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?"

Comment: Seems not to be available on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This work using default 2G /swapfile. Is there any particular reason/evidence for the increasing swap file to be the same as RAM size (case: RAM is 64GB)?

Comment: Note that this method can only work with unencrypted file partition and unencrypted swap. If you need actual security against attacker getting hardware access (e.g. thief stoling your laptop from cafe), you have to use full disk encryption and swap partition to enable resume from hibernation.

Answer (score 13):

And if you want to **turn on hibernation** in your Ubuntu *20.04**,
follow these steps:

1. First ensure you allocate swap memory in your machine to check:

   ```
   swapon --show
   ```
2. Then check whether the swap memory you allocated is more than or at least equal to the Physical memory(RAM).
3. Use the following command to find the swap partition:

   ```
   grep swap /etc/fstab
   ```
4. Copy the UUID of the output for example(`UUID=XXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-YYYYYYYYYY`).
5. Add a boot parameter by the following command:

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
6. At the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, add:

   ```
   resume=UUID=XXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-YYYYYYYYYY
   ```

   Note: In all other threads they used to ask to add swap partition but here we are adding the UUID value.

   The final line will be like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-YYYYYYYYYY"
   ```
7. Update the file:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
8. `sudo systemctl hibernate` and hibernation will now work in your Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If grep swap `/etc/fstab` does not give you swap's UUID try `sudo blkid`. Also, if `sudo systemctl hibernate` doesn't work, try `sudo hibernate`. I think you don't even need to edit grub because when you install `hibernate` it will detect your swap partition.

Comment: My RAM is 16 GB and my swap is 2 GB. How do I increase the swap to match the RAM?

Comment: what about if swapping is to a file instead of a partition?

Comment: @david.perez "Using a swap file requires also setting the `resume=swap_device` and additionally a `resume_offset=swap_file_offset` kernel parameters." https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file

Comment: Is this any different from the answer by eldwist?

Answer (score 11):

[eldwist's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241902/830570) worked for me, except...

...not initially, 'cos I got the following error:

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

If you get this error, you probably need to disable secure boot under the security menu in the UEFI/BIOS (see [similar problem with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd)). Then it worked for me (tested on Ubuntu 20.04; 5.4.0-33 kernel, configured for Dual-boot with Win10).

Comment: Secure Boot was enabled in my case and that is why it wasn't working. Very crucial point you have put.

Comment: you don't need to disable secureboot in your firmware - you can instead disable it in the shim loader with `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` I think this should keep bitlocker happy too

see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS#Method_2_-_Disable_Secure_Boot_in_shim-signed and hopefully this will all work out of the box soon: https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/55845.html

Comment: I recompiled the kernel to disable lockdown, this way I'm able to hibernate, have secure boot, and have a verified kernel core (no module verification, though).

Answer (score 8):

### To enable Hibernation in 20.04:

All of the examples on this page seem to be missing `resume-offset` it is necessary when using a swapfile rather than a swap partition.

**Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  /swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

**An error when using `dd` may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think it only works for me and for this person https://askubuntu.com/a/1247952/48214 if we disable Secure Boot. Is that true for you? Can you think of a way to enable Secure Boot too? Also, do you think `resume=swap_device` is required (which you didn't mention)? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2212070_1259645 Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure how to include secure boot, the laptop I have with me is a pre secure boot BIOS machine. I think `resume=swap_device` is equivalent to my `resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`. I use this method on my bootable USB flash drives and they normally work on the computers I plug them into okay.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04 and for adding an option in the power-off menu, I followed these instructions: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/?unapproved=3744061&moderation-hash=c5a82d0d3b6fc23e0cca2ec5e96996bb#comment-3744061

Comment: @Akronix: Your link was last updated November 21, 2022, almost 2 years after my answer was written.

Answer (score 6):

I just added a keyboard shortcut. I disabled the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, since I don't need it (the default action is to hide the window) and created a new shortcut with the command:

```
systemctl hibernate
```

Comment: systemctl hibernate did a shutdown without saving the current state, not what I expect from hibernation. -1

Answer (score 5):

[SuRa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259645/830570) at the top works great, however, if your laptop came with a swap **file** instead of a swap **partition** then you'll have to follow a few steps first to make it all work. At a high level:

1. Boot from live CD/USB drive, shrink you main partition by the amount of memory you have plus 1-2 GBs for margin. E.g. I have 16 GBs so I shrunk my partition by 18 GB for good measure. That will leave empty/unpartitioned space on your disk.
2. Create a new partition of type **swap** in the empty/unpartitioned space on your disk.
3. Reboot back into your installed OS (ie without the live CD/USB)
4. Go to "partitions" or "gparted" to get the UUID of your new swap partition.
5. Add your new swap **partition** to `/etc/fstab` and delete (or comment out) the old swap **file**
6. Use the `swapoff` and `swapon` commands to switch from the swap **file** to the swap **partition**
7. Don't forget to the delete the swap **file** to reclaim that space
8. Now you can follow SuRa's instructions.

Comment: Why do all this when you can hibernate to a swap file just fine?

Comment: This answer assumes that you do not have an encrypted volume with all your partitions in it (choosing encrypt disk from the install dvd)... I is simply pure insanity to opt for the Windows 95 level of security by NOT encrypting your drive. Therefor this answer solves for a use case that I really hope nobody has!

Answer (score 4):

#### Using a partition device instead of an UUID

I had to deviate a bit from the "how to" above, probably since I encrypted my hard drive. My `/etc/fstab` file does not contain an UUID for the swap partition but a partition device.

If your `/etc/fstab` contains a `<partition_device>` rather than a UUID for the swap partition, edit the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the file `/etc/default/grub` to contain `resume=<partition_device>`

Example:
if `/etc/fstab` contains this

```
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`/etc/default/grub` should contain the line

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1"
```

Then execute `sudo update-grub` and test by executing `sudo systemctl hibernate`

Comment: This did not work either... just boots up to a clean desktop...

Comment: Using an unencrypted partition as swap is NOT recommended.