# How to enable hibernate on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: hibernate

How can I enable hibernate on fresh installed system if it's possible.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=c14a936e-6c0f-4228-beec-c39bc515b157 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=1036-AA2D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I tried In /ect/default/grub - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=c14a936e-6c0f-4228-beec-c39bc515b157", but this is not working.
Thanks.

Comment: When using a swapfile you need to also add `resume_offset` to `/ect/default/grub`. See answer below.

Comment: C.S.Cameron thanks for reply, I done steps below and in result powering off(takes some longer) without saving opened programs and windows. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Writing swap data to disk takes longer than just shutting down. Booting the swap data also takes longer. How big is your RAM? Try booting, opening Terminal only and then typing `sudo systemctl hibernate`.  and then reboot. What does `sudo swapon -s` say?

Comment: `/swapfile                               file     2097148 0 -2`
Hibernate not working similar like in Windows OS, opened programs not staying opened after power on.

Comment: In Terminal what does `sudo swapon -s` report? What does `Free` report?

Comment: free report - `total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7915688     1732996     4514864      218924     1667828     5687960
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148`

Comment: My understanding is that for hibernation you should have 8GB swap space for 8GB of RAM. You show 2GB of swap. That might be enough to resume if you only have Terminal open, maybe not. Use `fallocate` or `dd` to enlarge swapfile to 8GB as show below. Please also send results of `sudo swapon -s`

Comment: `sudo swapon -s` result `Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/swapfile                               file     2097148 0 -2
`. Maybe I need to change swapfile to swap partition?

Comment: If you switch to a swap partition you will still require 8GB swap for your 8GB RAM. But you will not require `resume_offset=`. Personally I would try a 8GB swapfile before changing to a swap partition, but this is just personal preference. Some people prefer swap partitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Looks like yes, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### To enable Hibernation in 20.04:

**Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

**An error when using `dd` may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: I did as you said and did `sudo reboot` but the computer now is getting stuck on booting screen. And just before this it showed “Failed to activate swap /swapfile” what should I do. My PC is not turning ON, it is stuck on boot

Comment: When some thing like that happens to me I press the off button then try a reboot. I think there is a typo in the above, please change chown to chmod.

Comment: It keeps getting stuck on the boot screen. I did so many reboots

Comment: I don’t think I can do that now

Comment: Try pressing `e` at the grub menu and remove `resume=UUID=...` and `resume_offset=...` the edit will be temporary for one boot.

Comment: i don’t see `resume=UUID=..` or `resume_offset=` but I do see `root=UUID=... ro quiet splash...`. Is that the one?

Comment: Lets move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118822/discussion-between-c-s-cameron-and-an4s911).

Comment: Ok I am in chat