# How to enable hibernate option on menu in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, hibernate

I can only hibernate via command. I tried several alternatives, but none of them work, from extensions to GNOME, passing through the swap configuration (it's working), to editing the grub configuration file. I can't enable hibernation through the options menu.

Comment: Hibernate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290326/how-to-enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1290338#1290338

Answer (score -2):

I just created a keyboard shortcut to do it - you first disable the current super+H, then add new keyboard shortcut using "systemctl hibernate", then when you wish to hibernate, forget the menu - use super+H!

---

askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/