# sudo systemctl hibernate shows error 'Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation'

Tags: 20.04, swap, hibernate, ubuntu-gnome

I found so many others asking very similar questions to this. But I tried almost all of the solutions but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

When I enter `sudo systemctl hibernate` it gives me this error

> Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation

and this what I get when I enter `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.8Gi       982Mi       915Mi       3.9Gi       3.7Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi
```

as you can see there is enough space left in the `swapfile` but I am not able to hibernate it. If there is any more details or information I have to provide?

Comment: Are you using a swapfile or a swap partition? A swapfile needs `resume_offset` to be listed in GRUB after `resume=UUID`  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290326/how-to-enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts

Comment: I am using swapfile and it is in the directory `/swapfile`

Comment: My swapfile, (created by the installer), is in /. In your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, are `resume=UUID` and `resume_offset` listed?

Comment: I did what was mentioned in your answer in that link and I got stuck after doing `sudo reboot`. My PC is stuck on Boot. Before reaching this screen it showed some text including “Failed to activate swap /swapfile” and “Dependency failed for Swap”. What do I do?