# Help to merge unallocated space with primary partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I've tried to find examples online but with no luck. In ESXi extended VM disk from 60GB to 150GB and now I'm not seeing that extra space. I've loaded live CD but I'm afraid I will delete something and system will not be bookable. Any suggestions?

[image: Example of GParted]

Comment: You will need to delete the two `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda2` partitions before you are able to resize `/dev/sda1` to fill the whole disk. Be careful, though, there is no guarantee you will not run into boot issues.

Comment: If you run into boot problems, [you will need to repair boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). You might as well need to create a [swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165477/no-swapping-on-lubuntu-at-enabled-swap/1165500#1165500) after deleting your swap partition

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Right click and move your extended partition with swap to the right and then right click and resize your ext4 partition. the swap partition should not affect booting. You might want to create a larger swap partition without the extended partition. I assume that your system is backed up. You might want to create a swapfile that allows hibernation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290326/how-to-enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1290338#1290338

Comment: @Raffa: The swapfile link you provide does not allow hibernation. For that you need an offset.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'm on Debian 10.

Comment: I assume process should be the same if it was Ubuntu.
As you can see my issue is that I have extended swap in between.

Comment: I was able to get to work but I ran into error with Gparted. I was getting 
`Could not add this operation to the list
GParted Bug: A partition cannot end (46374912) after the end of
the device (%s)`

Comment: I solved with post https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/issues/86
by changing "Align to" to None.
Hope it helps someone.