# Kubuntu 20.10 does not hibernate when I close laptop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, power-management, hibernate

I've set system to hibernate when I close laptop in KDE settings, both for battery and cable. Hibernation works fine when I execute it from KDE menu but does not work when I close laptop despite system settings. Strange, but recently it was working correctly, don't know what happened and why now it is broken, I haven't touched anything related, only upgraded system from time to time. Grep dmesg by "hibernation" shows nothing interesting. Laptop - ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 8.

Could anybody help me get hibernation back to work?

UPD-1: Answers to some questions

Q1)

```
$ sudo ls /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/
10-vendor.d  20-org.d  30-site.d  50-local.d  90-mandatory.d
```

also there is

```
$ ls /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/
50-localauthority.conf  51-ubuntu-admin.conf
```

Q2)

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -E 'pm-utils|hibernate'
```

shows nothing, packages not installed

Q3)

```
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` and
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, I have no such files

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241902/226614 should work

Comment: 1) What do you have in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority`? 
2) Do you have packages `pm-utils` and `hibernate`? 
3) Please post the output of `cat /sys/power/state`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, updated question and added answers to your questions

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, one more thing from your link to another answer - executing `sudo systemctl hibernate` makes my laptop freeze. I see black screen and laptop didn't react to any buttons including short press on power button, I needed to long press power button for hard reset. It was definitely freeze and not hibernation because when in sleep mode LEDs on my laptop blinks and in this case they were enabled constantly like when it works normally (but it didn't react to anything as I've said).

Comment: Did you manage to test what I proposed in the answer?

Comment: I've faced strange thing - problem started to appear non-constantly, even though I haven't done nothing with it, maybe only updated some packages. Sometimes sleep works, sometimes don't. So now it is harder to test solutions of this trouble. I appreciate your help and will sent you bounty for your answer, but I could say if it works only later.

Comment: Good. Please post your results as you try.

Answer (score 0):

As per your answers, I suggest you try the following:

1. Make sure you have a swap partition at least as large as your RAM size (and please confirm you did so).
2. Install `pm-utils` and `hibernate`.
3. Add file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` with the following contents

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes

   [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
4. Execute `sudo pm-hibernate`.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and this works.
I am not certain this would avoid the freezes you get, but I guess it is worth trying.

Sources:

https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-linux

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/