# can not hibernate Ubuntu 20.04 (no disk /sys/power/state)

Tags: 20.04, power-management, hibernate

The referenced answer that stated in the closed message is not answering my question as you can see from my original post, I followed that answer and was not able to enable hibernation.

I am trying to follow [How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

But when I run this command:

```
cat /sys/power/state
```

I am getting this result:

```
freeze mem
```

Αnd for that reason, I can not hibernate. What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Τhe output of installing `pm-utils` and `hibernate` is the following:

```
$ sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hibernate is already the newest version (2.0+15+g88d54a8-1).
pm-utils is already the newest version (1.4.1-19).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
```

Also, the swap partition exists and its size is 19 GB (I have 16 GB RAM).

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb1                               partition   19104764    0   -2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @Coolguy3289 Obviously not, otherwise OP wouldn't have already referenced it!

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

In my case, I need to turn off fast boot and secure boot in bios.

They are hidden and difficult to find, so when I looked for them, I did not find originally and thought my mainboard BIOS doesn't have the option, but after looking all over the BIOS option, I found and turn them off and then I was able to hibernate.

Comment: (In my case fast boot could be left on.)