# hibernate doesn't happen ubuntu studio 20.04

Tags: hibernate

I enabled hibarnation by this article [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

but when after all I perform this command

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

system seems want to hibernate, turned off network but that is all what actually happen, it keep working. What may prevent from hibernation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: hibernate isn't enabled by default in any flavor.

Comment: @Coolguy3289 as I wrote in a post I did all from that topic and hibernation doesn't happen. Thats why I post this topic

Comment: @ThomasWard how to enable it?

Comment: @OleksandrIY see the linked thread.  If you followed all those steps and you have a swap *partition* (NOT swap files!) your hibernate won't work.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have swap file not partion. And followed all the steps