# wifi disabled upon resume from sleep mode in Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS

Tags: wireless, resume

Running a Gateway E-475M 64-bit laptop dual boot with WIN7PRO 64-bit and UBUNTU 20.04.2.0LTS and I can go into sleep mode even for just a few minutes and the wifi won't detect anything after resuming... no icon on the top bar, and going to select network the whole thing is empty... not seeing any wifi's in the area (normally there's 4 or 5 in range). Doesn't eventually wake up - just stays dead even though it is 'on'... was working fine upon resume a few days ago, but now this problem started. Have to just reboot cold to get the dang wifi on again... just logging out then back in doesn't wake the wifi - dumbfounded - could it be that freakin' avahi thing I had problems with on 18.04??

BTW - the WIN7PRO boot does not have any wifi issues going on/off sleep mode, and even hibernates with no wifi issues... just sayin'

removed avahi - still not waking wifi... I can go to settings => wifi and next to the words "visible networks" there is this spinning circle thing like it's looking...

FYI Had issues with my Ubuntu 18.04LTS laptop (locked at 4.15.0-70 generic), and my Lubuntu 18.04LTS laptop, both until I removed avahi... this 20.04LTS laptop was built on May 12,2021 working great and then after about 10 days this issue popped-up... unsettling!

Tried "You should unset in the wireless connection the checkbox "Connect automatically" – Gurupal singh" but still 'blank' for visible networks...

Tried "When you wake the device up again, try to run: sudo service network-manager stop then try: sudo service network-manager start. If this works, let me know. – Denny" but again.... yep no visible networks :-\

Tried "Try running this command from the Terminal when you wake your device from sleep - sudo modprobe -r wlp2s0 ; sudo modprobe wlp2s0;".... and still no wifi's available, even the wifi itself disappears from the menu....sheesh!

Pulling at straws here, but tried "My current solution is to run sudo killall NetworkManager each time I wake my computer" which the wifi in the drop-down disappears so no checking anything, then I run sudo service network-manager start and it's back, but still no wifi's available - man this is making me want to go back to using my Lubuntu 18.04 laptop since it suspends and no wifi issue... just a low-end 32-bit laptop (1.5Ghz w/1Gb ram) which is known for massive slowdowns :-[

INFO - pci comes up as intel pro wireless 3945ABG... the USB comes up as Realtek RTL8188EUS but is really a TP-LINK model TL-WN725N (go fig...)

Latest try: "I open a terminal window and run "sudo iwlist scan," the network is detected and connected to right away" => but with mine it is still 'down', only the USB is up - PCI dead as a door nail :-P
[I get wlp2s0 Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down; but for wlx8416f91d3f6d Scan complete : and it finds Cell 01 thru Cell 10...]

NO MORE BOUNTY OFFERS FROM ME (worthless)

Still got the issue - resume, and pci wifi goes out sooner or later and then never returns until reboot - on hibernate pci wifi works flawlessly, but restoring from hibernate takes FOREVER! Currently just plugged in network cable into lan from wifi extender and that works but not portable...

HERE is the results of lsmod | egrep 'module|iwp|iwl' and dmesg | grep -i iwl (after clearing dmesg first, wifi working, then suspending, then resuming and wifi went out):

sure wish I could get this output to look better - sorry!

```
> batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ lsmod | egrep 'module|iwp|iwl'
>iwl3945                94208  0
>iwlegacy              114688  1 iwl3945
>mac80211             1228800  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
>cfg80211              954368  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
>batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ 
>batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep -i iwl
>[   20.703742] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
>[   20.703748] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
>[   20.703750] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
>[   20.703825] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>[   20.767591] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
>[   20.767601] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
>[   20.767967] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
>[   25.556001] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
>[   61.110020] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep -i iwl
>[   20.703742] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
>[   20.703748] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
>[   20.703750] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
>[   20.703825] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>[   20.767591] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
>[   20.767601] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
>[   20.767967] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
>[   25.556001] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
>[   61.110020] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
>[  316.050830] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
>[  320.045831] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 696 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlegacy/common.c:97 _il_grab_nic_access+0xa8/0xc0 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831] Modules linked in: ccm binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ttm iwl3945 drm_kms_helper pcmcia snd_rawmidi iwlegacy snd_seq mac80211 coretemp snd_seq_device cec cfg80211 rc_core yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc i2c_algo_bit joydev fb_sys_fops wmi_bmof snd_timer syscopyarea input_leds sysfillrect serio_raw libarc4 at24 pcmcia_core snd sysimgblt tifm_7xx1 tifm_core soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid sdhci_pci lpc_ich pata_acpi hid psmouse firewire_ohci firewire_core cqhci ahci i2c_i801 i2c_smbus crc_itu_t libahci sdhci e1000e wmi video
>[  320.045831] RIP: 0010:_il_grab_nic_access+0xa8/0xc0 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il_wr_prph+0x35/0x90 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il_apm_init+0x1be/0x230 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_apm_init+0x1f/0x150 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_hw_nic_init+0x33/0x560 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  __il3945_up.part.0+0x70/0x140 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_mac_start+0x70/0x1c0 [iwl3945]
>[  320.990337] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  320.990353] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.117510] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.117519] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.244966] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.244973] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.372096] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.372102] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.499218] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.499223] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.500047] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
>[  322.513903] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.513917] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.641250] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.641261] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.768839] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.768848] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.896142] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.896151] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  323.023431] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  323.023441] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  323.023800] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
>[  323.958924] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  323.958940] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.086102] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.086112] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.213359] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.213372] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.340481] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.340487] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.467607] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.467613] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.467995] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
```

**ONE NEW NOTE:** disabled NetworkManager/network-manager and installed **WICD**, hoping and praying that it would fix this wifi driver crash **BUT** - still lose wifi upon resume after suspending - NUTS!!!

Comment: OK - here's the work around, but not the "answer": first add a simple USB wifi, next undo all 'auto connect' in settings (otherwise both wifi's will connect to the same wifi - not sure that is safe) - when you boot up, manually connect using USB wifi ONLY, not the internal PCI wifi - then when sleep mode wakes, you'll have to manually connect each waking... pain in the a**, but works until something fixes the main issue!

Comment: Interesting - upon fresh boot, both the PCI and USB wifi's are available, but once woken from sleep mode, the PCI goes 'dead'... hope this info helps ;-)

Comment: All this may be irrelevant as while messing with swapfile stuff, I just got HIBERNATE working, and on resume the wifi is fine... found info here for hibernate: 
- - - - - - - - - -
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04/1259645#1259645
- - - - - - - - - - 
then made keyboard shortcut super+H... awesome!

Comment: Ran across this little item: Currently, "hardware scanning is faster and more reliable and so is recommended for use with Network-Manager“. But unfortunately “iwl3945” driver does not support hardware scanning very well, however it is a default behavior that Network-Manager expects."
----------
you guessed it, my intel/pro wireless 3945ABG PCI wifi device uses the iwl3945 driver.... so, to actutally fix this in lieu of the USB wifi workaround, I need to do what's here:
---------
https://www.dotkam.com/2008/11/17/configure-iwl3945-driver-on-ubuntu/
---------
but I'm too scared to :-\

Comment: ...another note on hibernate vs suspend: I have to 'turn off' wifi (airplane mode comes up) before hibernating or I lose the PCI wifi upon restore.. then when I restore, I turn back on the wifi, then select network, and back up and running for internet... suspend loses the PCI no matter if I first cut off wifi (airplane mode) first or not... weird. Seems problem is with the linux iwl3945 driver - wish Ubuntu would fix it or something :-]

Comment: Recent development - while working on "resume from hibernation slow-down, freezing, locked-up issue"... seems the slow-down, etc. was due to my using manual, not auto, option for wifi. Upon messing with auto, I noticed the PCI wifi no longer gets corrupted (disappeared) but stays with me!!!! 

Of course resuming from suspend kills the PCI wifi EVERY TIME :-\
(still got some work to do on it, eh ubuntu?)

Comment: ...after switching from nm to wicd, wifi dies w/suspend still, but alas works w/hibernate :-|

Comment: ...dumped wicd - crceated too many bizarre 'quirks'. removal of wicd-gtk was easy, but incomplete as I kept seeing it in my top processes list and was still doing the weird stuff - gotta also purge its daemon separately (sudo apt-get purge wicd*) to completely get rid of it!

Comment: got another weird issue - seems there's two installs of network-nanager - a deb and a snap... laptop sending error reports to ubuntu about it :-|

Comment: after doing G4L backup and upgrading to 22.04LTS to see if “iwl3945” driver has been fixed... NOPE - problem ignored and persists.... so reformat and install G4L backup removing 'upgrade' and back to 20.04LTS... maybe by 24.04LTS it will be finally looked at?

Comment: ...maybe by 24.04LTS it will be finally looked at? (or replaced by something that works :-\