# Cannot enable hybernation due to missing swap UUID

Tags: grub2, swap

I have tried to follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04) in order to activate hybernation on my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS system.

However, I could not do it because in my fstab file the swap line does not provide a uuid as you can see below:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                       /etc/fstab                                 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=86a29cef-7076-4d45-9d5c-08065fd3e3fb /boot           ext4    defaults     >
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=6B80-CFF9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

  GNU nano 4.8                       /etc/fstab                                 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=86a29cef-7076-4d45-9d5c-08065fd3e3fb /boot           ext4    defaults     >
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=6B80-CFF9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Does anybody have recommendations?

Comment: Try instead `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1"` PS I'm not really sure if this works, please test it.

Comment: @paladin thank you for the suggestion but it did not work unfortunately. Any other idea?

Comment: You might use a swap partition instead of a swap file, this will have a UUID.