# Ubuntu 20.04 can't hibernate

Tags: swap, hibernate

I am still getting the message 'Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb "hibernate" not supported' when I use the command 'sudo systemctl hibernate' even after following the instructions found here: [How to hibernate with swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file#1132154). I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad L470 with 16GB of RAM. Following the instructions in the link above, I created a /swapfile corresponding to the size of my RAM. If there is anything else I need to do please help.

Comment: How big is your swapfile? Please do a`ls /swapfile -l`. Is your root filesystem maybe encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

Do the instructions here work?  [How to enable the hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)

> I assume you have a swap **partition** ready to use. (If you have a
> swap **file** you cannot hibernate)   Install `pm-utils` and
> `hibernate`:
>
> `$ sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate`
>
> Then:
>
> `$ cat /sys/power/state`
>
> You should see:
>
> `none freeze mem disk`
>
> Then run:
>
> `$ grep swap /etc/fstab`
>
> Copy the UUID value. You will need it later. Then run:
>
> `$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
>
> (or your favourite editor if not nano). Change the line that says
>
> `none GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
>
> so that it instead says:
>
> `none GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=YOUR_VALUE"`
>
> Then, after saving the file and quitting the text editor, run:
>
> `$ sudo update-grub`
>
> To test it, run:
>
> `$ sudo systemctl hibernate`
>
> Right now no GNOME extension is working to have the hibernate option
> back in the system menu.
>
> Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.4.0-31 on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1
> Carbon.