# How do I hibernate in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: swap, hibernate

I have used Windows a couple years. Sometimes I had to shutdown laptop because of power loss or travel and the hibernate feature helped me. Now after switching to Ubuntu I found there is no hibernate feature. I have read some  questions specifically this one.
[How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04)
Now after reading this guy's answer as he told I should have swap partition not swap file. Now unfortunately I have swap file. Now what if I wanted to hibernate **WITH** the swap file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To enable Hibernation in 20.04 using Swapfile:

**Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  /swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

**An error when using `dd` may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: After the first reboot it was stuck at the loading screen. I am kinda techy so I always press esc to see that Ido type something. It said failed to activate /swapfile Please help. I have windows usb disk and Ubuntu live usb

Comment: Ok the error was when you said to put # before UUID. Then I went to root through recovery mode then with a command mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda7 / which was my installation partition I got it in read write mode and then removed that # and rebooted. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernating is very fragile, and requires both operating system and driver support, both in linux and in windows.  If any part of the system doesn't support hibernation, it won't work.  Best case, it disables it and doesn't offer the option; worst case, the hibernation fails and you end up rebooting anyway, possibly after finding out some devices don't work correctly on wake up.

An answer in the question you linked to explains how to use a swapfile for hibernation.  However, you must satisfy several different conditions for this to work, and if any of them are not met, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

to continue [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355438/564125) answer, in my case, after doing with grub, it did not work, so I added a file to **initramfs-tools** config with the below content:

```
# write the resume UUID (make sure to replace this with your UUID)
echo RESUME=UUID=<Swap Device UUID> > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

# regenerate initramfs
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question that was asked?

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355438/564125) answer not worked for me and `grub` with `initramfs` correct hibernate on ubuntu for me.