# Unable to get swap file UUID for hibenation in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, swap, fstab, hibernate

I am following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-the-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04/1259645#1259645) to enable hibernation in my ubuntu 20.04LTS system. I followed exactly as mentioned in the first answer.
But when I run `grep swap /etc/fstab` to get the UUID value I get the below as the output.

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I don't understand where my UUID is. How do I enable hibernation in my system?

Comment: Files do not have UUIDs!

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Will you please clarify what you mean? That command is supposed to output the UUID of swapfile.

Comment: I haven't tried, but it may help if you follow the answer given **above** the one you shared the link of: https://askubuntu.com/a/1321773/855322

Comment: The swaplabel command will give you the UUID fo the swap file, but that may not be useful for your purpose. Might take the root (location of the swapfile) UUID plus an offset depending on how your root is set up (encryption,...).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the swapfile UUID for hibernation but the UUID of the swapfile's physical partition, which might not be your root partition. To enable hibernation follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file) instead.

To get the UUID of the swapfile which AFAIK is of no use try:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `swaplabel` command with `\swapfile` argument (sudo is needed).

```
$ sudo swaplabel /swapfile
UUID:  bb7f30c2-6d9d-4594-bcab-ed8e643ccb50
```