# Main menu does not show "Reboot" or "Hibernate", only "Suspend" and "Power off"

Tags: 20.04, power-management, hibernate, reboot, menu-bar

Since shortly ago,
the main menu does not show "Reboot" or "Hibernate", only "Suspend" and "Power off".
I do not recall anything happening that might have led to this.
Using kernel 5.13.0-40-generic.

How can I solve this?

I have enough swap space for hibernating, as shown by

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,6Gi       1,8Gi       2,6Gi       895Mi       3,3Gi       4,7Gi
Swap:         7,9Gi          0B       7,9Gi
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times where a UI does not help people get things done. The ellipsis beside "Power Off" is supposed to signify that there are more options when you click it:

[image: Power Off ...]

Which leads to:

[image: There they are]

There is the option to restart. If you would like to hibernate, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321773/1222991) will give you the walk-through

Comment: Pfff... silly me! (I am tempted to removing the post!)
The missing "Hibernate" made the menu look so short that I forgot about the other part. So the "Restart" part of the question is solved. As for the "Hibernate", the attempted explanation seems not correct. I am updating the question.

Comment: If you'd like to hibernate, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321773/1222991) will give you the walkthrough 

Comment: I already can hibernate (which is what that answer provides), via CLI. 
But the main menu doesn't show the option... this is what I want. I found a couple of options, I should try. If you have a proven, working way, please post it.