# E: Package 'hibernate' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo, hibernate, 22.04

Goal: To follow this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241902/1383985).

I've tried with no difference made:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
```

```
(base) me@ubuntu-pcs:~$ sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package hibernate is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hibernate' has no installation candidate
```

---

```
(base) daniel@ubuntu-pcs:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

---

```
(base) me@ubuntu-pcs:~$ hibernate | 2.0+15+g88d54a8-1 | focal/universe  | source, all
bash: focal/universe: No such file or directory
hibernate: command not found
source,: command not found
2.0+15+g88d54a8-1: command not found
```

Comment: Please clarify your release details; as your question says 20.04 in *tags* but paste shows a different release (22.04). `hibernate` is available for 20.04/focal but not 22.04  (`hibernate | 2.0+15+g88d54a8-1 | focal/universe  | source, all`)

Comment: Sorry, can confirm I'm using **22.04**. Check post for latest output

Comment: I downloaded the package from [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/hibernate) and installed it on Pop_OS 22.04 with no issues.