# No such device during systemd.hibernate on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

ubuntu 22.04 fail to hibernate with swap partition.
systemctl status systemd-hibernate

```
× systemd-hibernate.service - Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-06-10 15:31:27 EDT; 44min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-hibernate.service(8)
    Process: 5649 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5649 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4.614s

Jun 10 15:31:21 UX330 systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Jun 10 15:31:21 UX330 systemd-sleep[5649]: Entering sleep state 'hibernate'...
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd-sleep[5649]: Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: No such device
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd-sleep[5766]: /dev/sda:
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd-sleep[5766]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd-sleep[5766]:  APM_level        = 254
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:31:27 UX330 systemd[1]: Failed to start Hibernate.

sudo lsblk --fs

sda                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     FAT32 SYSTEM   218.1M    15% /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                                             
├─sda3 ntfs           OS                                           
├─sda4 ntfs           RECOVERY                                     
├─sda5 ext4     1.0            123.9G    23% /
└─sda6 swap     1              [SWAP]

$ free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            7834        1654        3888         379        2291        5543
Swap:           8433           0        8433

$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition   8636412     0       -2
```

/dev/sda is the only SSD in the system in /etc and not sure why hibernate service couldn't find it. /etc/fstab has the correct swap partition UUID.

Comment: Look at `sudo lsblk --fs`.

Comment: @waltnator updated in the description

Comment: Also add the output of the commands `free -m` and then `swapon -s`. This will show if any swap is being used and whether it is a file or a partition.

Comment: @user68186 updated

Comment: See the [accepted answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-the-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04). You may have to edit grub as described there.

Comment: @user68186 after installing pm-utils, machine seem suspended and rebooted after sudo systemctl hibernate.