# Enable Hibernation on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, hibernate

I am trying to enable hibernation on my system. Right now, I got sleep mode and sometimes it does not work. When it does work, it kills my battery life when I open my laptop.

When I use this command below, I get an error message:

```
root@OMEN:/# systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation
```

I found this article:

[Hibernation in Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231631/hibernation-in-kubuntu-20-04)

I dont have `swapon` on my system.

***UPDATE***

File System >> `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=f81f9e45-4f96-40e0-aaea-00f859ac559f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C682-3748  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: You must have as much swap space as you have RAM. Read `man mkswap swapon`.

Comment: @waltinator I will need more help on this.

Comment: @waltinator After created swapfile. I need it to enable it to use `swapon` I dont want to break my system. Can you help me?